# What is standard tuning for twelve string guitar?

Tags: guitar

I'm aware of a few different methods for tuning up a twelve string guitar.What is standard tuning for an acoustic twelve string guitar? Which pairs are tuned in unison and which pairs are tuned an octave apart?

Comment: [**_How do I ask a good question?_**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) : _Search, and research

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer_

Comment: @Stinkfoot - said in such an erudite way! This question really should not appear here.

Comment: @Tim:  Thanks - but I didn't write it! The bold is a link to the subject in  SExchange's guidelines for Q & A. This question also qualifies as a "google it" question, also mentioned up there.

Comment: @Stinkfoot Remember that questions that can be answered with a quick web search are actually **not** discouraged on Stack Exchange. In fact, part of the purpose of Stack Exchange is to be one of the top hits on such a web search. There have been conversations on the SE meta about this.

Comment: @Stinkfoot See in particular https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions and the linked questions. We are asked specifically not to criticize questions on the basis of how easy they may be to answer with a web search.

Comment: @ToddWilcox -  not exactly what it says up there. And note my citation in my first comment, which comes not from Meta QA's, but from the SO help center. Tnx

Comment: @Stinkfoot It's entirely possible I'm wrong in thinking that meta discussions refine and even override guidance in the help center. The top voted answer to the question I linked say "do not tell them to Google it". While you didn't write exactly that, your quote seems to me to imply that you are suggesting the asker should have done a web search rather than ask here. Further note this question is a duplicate of a question with a positive score.

Comment: @ToddWilcox : First words in the answer you cited: _Either answer nothing..._ . I answered nothing - simply cited the question guidelines in a comment. Whatever... more important things to worry about.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - given that this question is a duplicate, why hasn't that been noted with a close? It would also appear that several agree that it's not a good question for here, although I agree that in a google search this site should be a good place to find answers to questions such as this.

Comment: There is an old saying that goes" the only foolish question is the one that goes unasked". Makes good sense to me. And thanks for the answer to my question. I didn't mean to cause such a stink!

Answer (score 2):

The E A D and G strings are tuned in octaves, the B and e strings are in unison.